# class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity not found

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, dependencies, actionbarsherlock

**THE ANSWER**

The answer was to check the Export box. Thanks to Chris Tarazi for the answer. Unfortunately i cannot upvote comments and answer my own question yet because of my reputation.

**The question was:**

I have an Android project where i am using the SlidingMenu Library (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). I have succesfully added the Slidingmenu library to my Android project and made a working example using the SlidingMenu.

**What i want to add:**

Now i want to add an extra library on top of the SlidingMenu. Because if i add an extra library on top of SlidingMenu i will get more features available. But my Android project is still using SlidingMenu.

**Problem:**

The extra library on top of the SlidingMenu library is ActionBarSherlock. As soon as i integrate and use the ActionBarSherlock library i'll get a compile error with the following message:

> java: cannot access com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity   class
>   file for com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity not found

**Code setup:**

Class from Android project:

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Code from SlidingMenu (without ActionBarSherlock):

```
public class SlidingActivity extends Activity implements SlidingActivityBase
```

Code from SlidingMenu (with ActionBarSherlock):

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;    
public class SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity implements SlidingActivityBase
```

So my MainAcvitity is using SlidingActivity(from SlidingMenu) and SlidingActivity is using SherlockActivity(from ActionBarSherlock).

**My dependency settings:**

I have created a Android Project that uses SlidingMenu library. SlidingMenu has a dependency to ActionBarSherlock library. Android Project > SlidingMenu > ActionBarSherlock

I can't use the image tag yet, so here is an url to my dependency settings in IntelliJ https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRm7B.jpg

Comment: Try checking the "Export" box in the 3rd image.

Comment: there is no need to use sliding menu use NavigationDrawer. no need to use actionbarsherlock can use AppCompat for backward compatibility

Comment: I agree with @Raghunandan. Using Feinstein SlidingMenu with ActionBarSherlock is more complex than using NavigationDrawer.